# Can't create user in AD

Tags: active-directory

Now I research that product how MidPoint (Identity Management System) and try create user in MidPoint and get it in Active Directory. MidPoint is connected to Active Directory using a connector com.evolveum.polygon.connector.ldap.ad.AdLdapConnector. The idea is that I create a user in MidPoint and bind this connector to it. This should be enough according to the documentation for the user to be created in Active Directory as well.But when i try to do this i get the error `org.identityconnectors.framework.common.exceptions.PermissionDeniedException(Error adding LDAP entry CN=John Doe,CN=Users,DC=test-idm,DC=ru: unwillingToPerform: 0000001F: SvcErr: DSID-031A1236, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0?? (53)).`

Can someone tell me what exactly this error means? I haven't been able to find any answers on the internet about it.

Thank you.

Comment: `DSID-031A1236` usually indicates the transport used isn't secure enough for the operation. Have you configured MidPoint to talk to AD over TLS (LDAPS on port 636 instead of LDAP on 389)?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Port on LDAP 389. Now I learned that SSL/TSL is not configured on AD. Do I need to set it up to make it work?

Comment: The communication must be encrypted to set the password (which I assume it's doing). LDAPS is one way (and maybe the simplest) but you can also use Kerberos (which can work over port 389, but might be harder to setup or not even possible with MidPoint).